# VB.NET Converting a For Loop to LINQ with nested for loops

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a for loop that I'm seeing if I can convert to LINQ. I've managed to get most of it working however the personObject class has a list of address and this is something I'm finding difficult to convert

The VB.NET for loop is as follows:

```
DTOObject.Person = new list(Of person)

If object.Person.count > 0 Then
    For each personObject as person in object.Person
        dim data as new DTOPerson with { .FirstName = personObject.firstName, .Surname = personObject.surname}
        
        For each address as person.address in object.Person.Address
            dim address as new DTOPersonAddress with {.ID = address.id }
            personObject.Address.add(address)
        Next
    Next

    DTOObject.Person.add(data)
End If
```

I can get the following LINQ working but not able to get the address collection added:

```
DTOObject.Person = new list(Of person)
If object.Person.count > 0 Then
    DTOObject.Person.AddRange(from personObject in object.Person
                  Select New DTOPerson() With {
                  .FirstName = personObject.firstName, 
                  .Surname = personObject.surname
})

DTOObject.Person.add(data)
End If
```

Comment: Should `personObject.Address.add(address)` actually be `data.Address.add(address)` in the first code snippet? You've made your code confusing by using the same words in many places to mean different things. Better names would kame the code easier to read.

Comment: For one thing, collection properties should have pluralised names, e.g. a property that is a collection of `Address` objects should be named `Addresses`, not `Address`. The latter implies a single `Address` object. Don't abandon the logic that you've used every day of your life when you start programming.

Comment: poor naming conventions here for sure. Also it appears `data` would be out of scope since it is outside of both for loops. Converting this to LINQ is fine, but I think your actual code needs some addressing first as well. Lastly, do you need the check for a count on object.Person? Seems as if you should just be able to run your for each loop over it.

Comment: What is the purpose of all the `object.` in your code?

Comment: .Net programming is a matter of types. What is the type of `personObject.Address`?